# ODS TRACE in SAS

Tags: statistics, sas

I'm trying to pick the top 3 correlated variables with a certain variable. I ran a correlation analysis between this variable and a set of other variables using the following code:

```
ods trace on;
proc corr data=all_base_corr outp=corr1;
var DEPVAR;
with VAR1 VAR2 VAR3 VAR4 VAR5 VAR6 VAR7 VAR8 VAR9;
ods select PearsonCorr ;
run;
ods trace off;
```

I only selected PearsonCorr  table in the output because that's all I'm interested in, However it gives me a bunch of other statistics other than correlation values such as Mean, Std and N and I'm note sure how to get rid of those in the output.
Basically I want to have a table with the list of variables in one column and the correlation value in a second column, so that I can sort and pick the top 3 correlated variable.

I appreciate any feedback and solutions.
Thank you,
SE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `proc corr` statement, you are able to specify the type of stats you want to see.  You specify the `_type_` keyword to select.  The details are here:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_appssds_sect006.htm

Please let me know if that's not what you're looking for.

Best of luck!

Comment: Excellent!  When you get a chance, please choose this answer as the correct one so others can find it if they search for this same problem later.  Thanks, and take care.